# Granular policy over istio egress trafic

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, istio, servicemesh

I have kubernetes cluster with installed Istio. I have two pods, for example, sleep1 and sleep2 (containers with installed curl). I want to configure istio to permit traffic from sleep1 to www.google.com and forbid traffic from sleep2 to www.google.com.

So, I created ServiceEntry:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: google
spec:
  hosts: 
  - www.google.com
  - google.com
  ports: 
  - name: http-port
    protocol: HTTP
    number: 80
  resolution: DNS
```

Gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http-port
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

two virtualServices (mesh->egress, egress->google)

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: mesh-to-egress
spec:
  hosts: 
  - www.google.com
  - google.com
  gateways:
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: egress-to-google-int
spec:
  hosts: 
  - www.google.com
  - google.com
  gateways:
  - istio-egressgateway
  http:
  - match: 
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: google.com
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
```

As result, I can curl google from both pods.

And the question again: can i permit traffic from sleep1 to www.google.com and forbid traffic from sleep2 to www.google.com? I know that this is possible to do with kubernetes NetworkPolicy and black/white lists (https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/), but both methods are forbids (permits) traffic to specific ips or maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create different service accounts for `sleep1` and `sleep2`. Then you [create an RBAC policy](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authz-http/#enforcing-service-level-access-control) to limit access to the `istio-egressgateway` policy, so `sleep2` will not be able to access any egress traffic through the egress gateway. This should work with forbidding any egress traffic from the cluster, that does not originate from the egress gateway. See https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/#additional-security-considerations.

If you want to allow `sleep2` access other services, but not `www.google.com`, you can use Mixer rules and handlers, see [this blog post](https://istio.io/blog/2018/egress-monitoring-access-control/#access-control-by-mixer-policy-checks-part-2). It shows how to allow a certain URL path to a specific service account.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably on the right track on the denial option.
It is also not limited to IP as we may see attribute-based example for [Simple Denial](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/#simple-denials) and [Attribute-based Denial](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/#attribute-based-whitelists-or-blacklists)

So, for example, if we write a simple denial rule for Sleep2 -> www.google.com:

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: denySleep2Google
spec:
  compiledAdapter: denier
  params:
    status:
      code: 7
      message: Not allowed
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: denySleep2GoogleRequest
spec:
  compiledTemplate: checknothing
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: denySleep2
spec:
  match: destination.service.host == "www.google.com" && source.labels["app"]=="sleep2"
  actions:
  - handler: denySleep2Google
    instances: [ denySleep2GoogleRequest ]
```

Please check and see if this helps.
Also, the "match" field in the "rule" entry is based on istio expression language around the attributes. Some vocabulary can be found in [this doc](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/attribute-vocabulary/).

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work. I still can access google page from sleep2. Also, I've tried delete "destination" condition and leave only source labels and this still doesn't work

Comment: I see. Just to understand the situation better, is your **global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode** ALLOW_ANY or REGISTRY_ONLY? The policies will only be enforced for external services if mode is REGISTRY_ONLY. You can check this [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#envoy-passthrough-to-external-services).

To my knowledge, we need to enforce REGISTRY_ONLY first, and then the blacklisting applies. Kindly try this out and see if it sheds light.

Comment: REGISTRY_ONLY (+ServiceEntry for google from original post). I want to try solution from another answer, maybe traffic from my pods can go egress bypass

Comment: Alright.

If you want to revisit later the sample denier i suggested above, the `destination.service.host` in the `match` part may not be correct. Do try `connection.requested_server_name` when you have time.